# SolrCloud don't start, it behave differently on server and local

Tags: java, solr, solr4, solrcloud

I am trying solr cloud on my server. The server is a virtual machine. My solr version is 4.x

I have followed solr cloude wiki " http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud ".
When I run solr Cloud, It is failed.  But If I try on my local ,it runs successfully.

**Why does solr behave differently on server and local?**

My solr.log as follows:

```
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:50:13.389; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
ERROR - 2013-09-12 14:50:13.433; org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer; CoreContainer was not shutdown prior to finalize(), indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!  instance=1423856966
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:50:13.483; org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector; Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:01.776; org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server; jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:01.838; org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider; Deployment monitor /opt/Applications/solr-4.4.0/example/contexts at interval 0
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:01.846; org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager; Deployable added: /opt/Applications/solr-4.4.0/example/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:02.549; org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor; NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:02.656; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; SolrDispatchFilter.init()
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:02.797; org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader; JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:02.799; org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader; solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:02.801; org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader; new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'solr/'
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:02.917; org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr; Loading container configuration from /opt/Applications/solr-4.4.0/example/solr/solr.xml
ERROR - 2013-09-12 14:57:03.072; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
ERROR - 2013-09-12 14:57:03.098; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load SOLR configuration
   at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr.fromFile(ConfigSolr.java:65)
   at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr.fromSolrHome(ConfigSolr.java:89)
   at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.<init>(CoreContainer.java:139)
   at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.<init>(CoreContainer.java:129)
   at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:139)
   at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:122)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr.fromInputStream(ConfigSolr.java:84)
   at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr.fromFile(ConfigSolr.java:62)
   ...41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at gnu.xml.transform.TransformerImpl.transform(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.solr.core.Config.copyDoc(Config.java:173)
   at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:135)
   at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr.fromInputStream(ConfigSolr.java:79)
   ...42 more

INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:03.100; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
INFO  - 2013-09-12 14:57:03.150; org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector; Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
```

Comment: what is the command used ? from where is it fired ? whats the directory structure and files in it ?

Comment: java -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/collection1/conf -Dcollection.configName=myconf -DzkRun -DnumShards=2 -jar start.jar

Comment: My problem is solved. My server default java version is 1.5 . I upgrade java version.